# pregsplit - how to group together alphanumeric character and "_"?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have the following expression in pregsplit:

```
$content = preg_split('/([\p{P}\p{S}])|\s/', $file, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Now if the content of the input file was `int somenumber;`

It would split into:

```
int
somenumber
;
```

If it was int `some_number;` what I'd get is:

```
int 
some
_
number
;
```

However, what I'd like is:

```
int
some_number
;
```

Is there a way to edit this expression to group together alphanumeric characters + the "_" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_` is matched by `\p{P}` (punctuation property class). Restrict it with the `(?!_)` negative lookahead:

```
$content = preg_split('/((?!_)[\p{P}\p{S}])|\s/', 'int some_number;', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/smtmf3) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6fSPI5/1).

With this `(?!_)[\p{P}\p{S}]`, all punctuation and symbol characters with the exception of `_` can be matched.